# "this" java point of inquiry

Tags: java, this

Recreational Android developer here, with what I would guess is a simple query.

I am wondering exactly what "this" means in java/Android. Occasionally you see it as an inherent part of some methods, but I am curious what, in detail, it really refers to. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

From my view *this* is:

- one of fifty Java keywords
- **special** (e.g. read-only) reference to the **current** object

You can use it in four different contexts:

1. to point to the current object's **fields** and **methods** (this.)
2. to point to the current **object** itself (e.g. Object object = this;)
3. to invoke **constructor** in an another constructor (this())
4. (Qualified this) to point to the **outer object** in (not static) inner class (e.g. OuterClassName.this.OuterClassField)

To get better understanding you need some example:

```
class Box {
   // Implementing Box(double width = 1, double length = 1, double height = 1):
   Box(double width, double length, double height) {         
      this.width = width; // width is local parameter
      this.length = length; // this.length is object's field
      this.height = height;
   }
   Box(double width, double length) {
      // no statements here allowed
      this(width, length, 1);
      // you can call at most one constructor (recursion not allowed)
   }
   Box(double width) {
      this(width, 1, 1);
   }
   Box() {
      this(1, 1, 1);
      System.out.println("I am default constructor");
   }
   public double getWidth() {
       return this.width; // explicit way (width means the same)
       // return Box.this.width; // full-explicit way
   }
   public void showWidth() {
       System.out.println(this.getWidth());
   }
   public void showWidthAlternate() {
       Box box = this; // the same as explicitly Box box = Box.this;
       // this = box; // can't touch me (read-only reference)
       System.out.println(box.width);
   }
   private double width, length, height;
}
```

More information:

- JLS [15.8.3 this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.3) and [15.8.4 Qualified this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.8.4)
- [Using the this Keyword](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) (Oracle tutorial)

Answer (score 4):

`this` is used to refer to the current class instance.  See http://www.javabeat.net/qna/16-what-is-super-and-this-keyword-in-java/

Answer (score 1):

this refers to the current object

used mostly when a field is shadowed

for example:

```
class Example {

int x;

public void setSomething(int x) {
 this.x = x;
}

}
```

this.x is refering to the instance of x in the Example class not the x passed into the method.

I edited to add the link if you want to read more:

[this keyword](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Answer (score 0):

It refers to the instance of the class on which the method was called.

For example, if you have:

```
Cow buddy;
...
buddy.moo();
```

If the "moo()" method uses "this" inside of its definition, it will refer to the Cow "buddy".